# Can't move polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I'm new to using GIS software, but does anyone know how to move a polygon in QGIS 2.18.8? I use the move polygon feature with an old version, but with the recent updates that feature is not working.

Although the button is available, when I click "Toggle Editing" on a polygon layer, the "move polygon" feature is not available now. Any idea on how to move a polygon in a different method?

Answer (score 13):

You need to be sure that the polygon is in "Toggle Editing" mode.

[image]

The next step is to press the "Move Feature(s)" button on the menu.

[image]

Once it done go to the polygon and move it wherever you like.

[image]