# Moving individual polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, polygon-creation, multi-polygon

In QGIS I am using the "BreederMap" plugin to define the layout of a large wheat field trial with 10m2 plots. Unfortunately, the lines are not exactly straight (sowing done without GPS and steering)

I would like to be able to move my individual polygons to arrange for the plots.

Is this possible?

Here is a screenshot of how it looks.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to edit them one at a time? If so start editing, select a polygon and drag it to where you want. If you're trying to move corners then that can be done with vector editing https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html

Comment: Are your polygons all separate features, or parts of one MultiPolygon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the polygon layer is in Editing mode (use the **Toggle Editing** button on the **Digitzing Toolbar**, or *Layer->Toggle Editing*).

[image]

Then select the **Move Feature** tool from the **Advanced Digitizing Toolbar**. If you can't see it, enable the toolbar under *View->Toolbars->Advanced Digitizing Toolbar*

[image]

Then you can click on a polygon, move the cursor, and click again to drop.

[image]

[ There is a similar answer in a now closed question: [Can't move polygons in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241668/cant-move-polygons-in-qgis) ]